# blockchain.info says transaction is complete but electrum dosnt show it

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, electrum

https://blockchain.info/address/12tFogx4zzsZzCwWAXfb36gaPHkt3FNU3P?filter=5# is the transaction page for my wallet address help? i just got $9 and i want it in my wallet but its not there (its almost been 24 hours and blockchain says i have it??) i just recently upgraded to electrum 1.9.4

Comment: and i tryed regening the blockchan it did nothing but waste my time lol

Comment: I'm just curious as to whether it could be an Electrum 1.9 issue, as 2.4 is current. Have you got the private key for 12tFogx4zzsZzCwWAXfb36gaPHkt3FNU3P?  Go to console, then `dumpprivkey 12tFogx4zzsZzCwWAXfb36gaPHkt3FNU3P?` then import it to a mobile wallet or Electrum 2.0. Also, is it possible the wallet sent your BTC to a change address? If this is the case, that wif won't match 12tFogx4zzsZzCwWAXfb36gaPHkt3FNU3P